# Открытие одного подменю, а не всех сразу

Tags: jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.link').click(function(event) {
      $('.list__sublist').slideToggle();
      event.preventDefault();
    });
  });
```

```css
.list__sublist {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list__item">
    <a class="link" href="">List #1</a>
    <ul class="list__sublist">
      <li class="list__item"><a href="">Item list #1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="list__item"><a href="">Item list #1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="list__item"><a href="">Item list #1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="list__item"><a href="">Item list #1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="list__item"><a href="">Item list #1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="list__item">
    <a class="link" href="">List #2</a>
    <ul class="list__sublist">
      <li class="list__item"><a href="">Item list #2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="list__item"><a href="">Item list #2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="list__item"><a href="">Item list #2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="list__item"><a href="">Item list #2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="list__item"><a href="">Item list #2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Как сделать, чтоб при клике на `.link` открывалось соответствующее меню, а не все сразу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Берём следующий элемент от того на который кликнули

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.link').click(function(event) {
      $(this).next(".list__sublist").slideToggle();
      event.preventDefault();
    });
  });
```

```css
.list__sublist {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list__item">
    <a class="link" href="">List #1</a>
    <ul class="list__sublist">
      <li class="list__item"><a href="">Item list #1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="list__item"><a href="">Item list #1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="list__item"><a href="">Item list #1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="list__item"><a href="">Item list #1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="list__item"><a href="">Item list #1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="list__item">
    <a class="link" href="">List #2</a>
    <ul class="list__sublist">
      <li class="list__item"><a href="">Item list #2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="list__item"><a href="">Item list #2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="list__item"><a href="">Item list #2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="list__item"><a href="">Item list #2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="list__item"><a href="">Item list #2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

или делаем поиск элемента если разметка может поменяться:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.link').click(function(event) {
      $(this.parentNode).find(".list__sublist").slideToggle();
      event.preventDefault();
    });
  });
```

```css
.list__sublist {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list__item">
    <a class="link" href="">List #1</a>
    <ul class="list__sublist">
      <li class="list__item"><a href="">Item list #1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="list__item"><a href="">Item list #1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="list__item"><a href="">Item list #1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="list__item"><a href="">Item list #1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="list__item"><a href="">Item list #1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="list__item">
    <a class="link" href="">List #2</a>
    <ul class="list__sublist">
      <li class="list__item"><a href="">Item list #2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="list__item"><a href="">Item list #2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="list__item"><a href="">Item list #2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="list__item"><a href="">Item list #2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="list__item"><a href="">Item list #2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).children('.list__sublist').slideToggle();
```