# Закрывать выпадающее меню при клике на соседний пункт меню

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть менюшка на 3 пункта, каждый из которых - выпадающий. По клику на пункт меню появляется выпадающее меню. Но проблема в том, что я могу открыть несколько таких меню одновременно, а мне нужно, чтобы они открывались по очереди. И в случае, если одно подменю уже открыто, то по клику на соседний пункт меню подменю скрывалось. Функция открытия подменю:

```
$(function() {
    var touch = $('li .menu-link');
    var w = $(window).width();

    $(touch).on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var menu = $(this).closest('li').find('.dropdown-list');
        menu.slideToggle(0);
    });

    $(window).resize(function(){
        var menu = $('li .menu-link ~ .dropdown-list');
        if(w > 992 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
            menu.removeAttr('style');
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu-item-list desktop-menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="menu-link drop-down">Билеты</a>
        <div class="dropdown-list">
            <div class="menu-items">
                <a href="#"><i style="color: #ff6f00;" class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Спецпредложения</a>
                <a href="#"><i style="color: #ffb300;" class="material-icons">star_rate</i>Популярные рейсы</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="menu-link drop-down">Информация</a>
        <div class="dropdown-list">
            <div class="menu-items">
                <a href="#"><i style="color: #0277bd;" class="material-icons">airplanemode_active</i>Авиакомпании</a>
                <a href="#"><i style="color: #f44336;" class="material-icons">place</i>Аэропорты</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="menu-link drop-down">Компания</a>
        <div class="dropdown-list">
            <div class="menu-items">
                <a href="#"><i style="color: #8bc34a;" class="material-icons">info</i>О нас</a>
                <a href="#"><i style="color: #1565c0;" class="material-icons">help</i>Поддержка</a>
                <a href="#"><i style="color: #607d8b;" class="material-icons">email</i>Контакты</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="menu-link profile-link"><i class="material-icons">person</i>Личный кабинет</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Для приличия можно было и html разметку со стилями приложить. Но применять slideToggle в данном случае не нужно. Надо просто все прятать, а один конкретный (на котором был произведен клик) выдвигать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский добавил html. Стилей там на строк 300.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Открытие одного подменю, а не всех сразу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/553057/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8e-%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%85-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Алгоритм такой: сначала нужно закрыть все подменю `slideUp()`, а потом если "кликнутое" меню было закрыто, открыть его - `slideDown()`

```js
$(function() {
  var touch = $('li .menu-link');
  var menuWrapper = $('.menu-item-list');
  var w = $(window).width();

  $('html').click(function() {
    menuWrapper.find('.dropdown-list').slideUp(0);
  });

  menuWrapper.click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  $(touch).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var menu = $(this).closest('li').find('.dropdown-list');
    var isClosed = menu.is(':hidden'); // закрыто ли подменю, по которому кликнули

    menuWrapper.find('.dropdown-list').slideUp(0); // закрываем все подменю

    // если меню было закрыто, то открываем его
    if (isClosed) {
      menu.slideDown(0);
    }
  });

  // ...
});
```

```html
<div>outside</div>
<ul class="menu-item-list desktop-menu">
  <li>

    <a href="#" class="menu-link drop-down">Билеты</a>
    <div class="dropdown-list">
      <div class="menu-items">
        <a href="#"><i style="color: #ff6f00;" class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Спецпредложения</a>
        <a href="#"><i style="color: #ffb300;" class="material-icons">star_rate</i>Популярные рейсы</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="menu-link drop-down">Информация</a>
    <div class="dropdown-list">
      <div class="menu-items">
        <a href="#"><i style="color: #0277bd;" class="material-icons">airplanemode_active</i>Авиакомпании</a>
        <a href="#"><i style="color: #f44336;" class="material-icons">place</i>Аэропорты</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="menu-link drop-down">Компания</a>
    <div class="dropdown-list">
      <div class="menu-items">
        <a href="#"><i style="color: #8bc34a;" class="material-icons">info</i>О нас</a>
        <a href="#"><i style="color: #1565c0;" class="material-icons">help</i>Поддержка</a>
        <a href="#"><i style="color: #607d8b;" class="material-icons">email</i>Контакты</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="menu-link profile-link"><i class="material-icons">person</i>Личный кабинет</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

**UPD.**

> Спасибо, всё работает! Ещё вопрос один: а можно сделать так, что если
>   был сделан клик вне dropdown-list, то чтобы он закрывался?

Нужно добавить обработчик кликов на всей странице `$('html').click(/*...*/)`, в котором закрывать все открытые меню. Но если мы работаем в самом меню, то вызывать `e.stopPropagation();` - останавливает "всплытие" вызова события к родительским элементам. Вызывать нужно в событии, где не нужно "принудительно" закрывать меню (например внутри `.menu-item-list`).

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает! Ещё вопрос один: а можно сделать так, что если был сделан клик вне dropdown-list, то чтобы он закрывался?

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin обновил ответ